# Adding a top layer to Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, layer

I'm using the latest Bootstrap V 3.3.2 and basically I'm trying to create a carousel (which I've done) but I want to add a top layer that has a cutout with a design. I want to have pictures in the background moving relatively quickly that can only be seen through the cutout. How can I accomplish this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>title</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</header>


<!-- Bootstrap Core Javascript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Carousel -->
<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 500 //changes the speed
})
</script>

</body>

</html>


html,
body {
height: 100%;
}

/*========================================
carousel
========================================*/
.carousel,
.item,
.active {
height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
height: 100%;
}

/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is the consept: try to use in `style` `background-size: cover;`

in fact, if I stood in front of me such problem - I have created a few blocks one that is due in part to hide the carousel - set to his `background-size: cover` and moved in front throw `index-z` .

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.